# extjs add items to a formpanel in a row dynamically

Tags: javascript, extjs3, form-layout

Using ExtJS 3.4 -  I have a formpanel which lays out three buttons in a row. I believe the right way to do this is to nest item blocks, code shows what I am doing.

```
var myPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
    id:'myPanel',
    height:300,
    width: 800,
    items:[{
        layout : 'column' ,border:false,buttonAlign : 'left', bodyStyle : 'padding:15px 20px 0',
        items:[{
                      layout:'column' , border:false,  
                      items:[saveSelectedButton, deleteSelectedButton, cancelButton ]
               }]
      }]


});
```

What I really need to do is add the buttons dynamically so the items block is empty at first `items:[]` and then I call

```
myPanel.add(saveSelectedButton, deleteSelectedButton, cancelButton);
```

but the buttons are rendered in a column, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of `buttons` instead of `items` is more preferred way.

```
var myPanel = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
// ... 
    buttons:[saveSelectedButton, deleteSelectedButton, cancelButton]  
});
```

For adding them dynamically you should use `addButton` method. E.g.

```
var form = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
        title: 'Test',
        el: 'test',
        url: '',
        method: '',
        items: [{}],
        buttons: [{}]
    });
    form.addButton({
        text: 'Test Button',
        id: 'test-button',
        type: 'submit'
    });
    form.render();
```